# Proving that a function between two specific topological spaces can't be both continuous and injective

Tags: general-topology

I'm having trouble solving this problem.
Let $\mathcal B=\{\emptyset,(m,n)\}_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ a family of subsets, prove it is a base for $\mathbb{R}$, and let $Y=(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{U}_B)$. Then consider the following topological space:
$$X=\mathbb{R}\times Y $$
where $\mathbb{R}$ has the usual topology.
The problem is:

> prove that there are no function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}^2$ that are continuous and injective.

Regarding the first part, I showed that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $\mathbb{R}$.
Coming to the second part, I can't prove there are no such function.

I tried assuming $f$ is injective and then proving it can't be continuoius (and viceversa), but I am stuck.

Assuming $f$ is injective, I considered an open set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and considered $f^{-1}(A)\subseteq X$. I want to show $f^{-1}(A)$ is not open in $X$ so it cannot be seen as $f^{-1}(A)=U\times V$ where $U,V$ are open sets of respectively  $\mathbb{R}$ and $Y$.
Does anyone have an idea about how to procede?

Comment: I would try to consider the map $$ g:Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, g(x)=f(0,x).$$ This map should be continuous and injective. Then we can pick $v=g(0)$ and write $$ \{ 0 \} =g^{-1}(v) = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} g^{-1}(B(v, 1/n)).$$ Then we should be able to use that open sets in $Y$ contain a full interval to conclude that the big intersection contains an interval and get a contradiction. Disclaimer: I am pretty tired, check and see for yourself how much of this is nonsense :) have fun.

Comment: Suggestion: show that any space which admits a continuous injection into a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff.

Comment: @MikeF thank you, eye-opener comment !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.
Since $X$ is not Hausdorff, exist at least two different point that are not separable. We name this two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}^2$ injective, it follows that $f(x_1,y_1)\neq f(x_2,y_2)$. But $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff, then exists open sets $V=U_{f(x_1,y_1)}$ and $W=U_{f(x_2,y_2)}$ s.t $f(x_1,y_1)\in V$,$f(x_2,y_2)\in W$ and $V \cap W=\emptyset $. If $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(V)$ and $f^{-1}(W)$ are open and in particular $f^{-1}(V) \cap f^{-1}(W)=\emptyset$ and hence $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are separable. Whence $f$ can't be continuous.

Conversely, let $f$ be a continuous function. If we assume $f$ as injective,
we have the following condition: $(x_1,y_1)\neq(x_2,y_2) \implies f(x_1,y_1)\neq f(x_2,y_2)$. Since $f(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,2$ is in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and is $\mathbb{R}^2$ Hausdorff, there must exist open sets $V=U_{f(x_1,y_1)}$ and $W=U_{f(x_2,y_2)}$ such that $f(x_1,y_1)\in V$,$f(x_2,y_2)\in W$ and $V \cap W=\emptyset $. Now, since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(V)$ and $f^{-1}(W)$ are open in $X$ and $f^{-1}(V) \cap f^{-1}(W)=\emptyset$. Applying this reasoning, we obtain that all points are separable in $X$, that is absurd since $X$ is not Hausdorff. Whence $f$ can't be injective.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: There are some strange things (what exactly is the purpose of the paragraph which begins "conversely"? It seems you are again proving what you proved before...) and some minor imprecisions (you should probably make it clear that, e.g., $f(x_1,y_1) \in U$ and $(x_1,y_1) \in f^{-1}(V)$), but all the main ideas are there. Could just use some tidying up is all. Another stylistic point: it is typically better to not phase one's proofs as proofs by contradiction when it does not add to the argument.

Comment: @MikeF Thank you again for the comment. I edited my answer, adding more details to the second part of the proof. Maybe is too long and can be done all in one shot.

Comment: +1. I like it....................

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Appreciate it, thank you for the nice comment :)

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are different points in a Hausdorff space, there exist open sets $V$ and $W$ such that $V \cap W=\varnothing$ **and** $\mathbf{p \in U}$, $\mathbf{q \in V}$. You should make the bold part explicit. Maybe, in your course, writing $V=U_p$ and $W=U_q$ implies this? However, this notation isn't universal, so it's hard to judge. I'd also say your paragraph 1 and paragraph 2 have a lot of overlap. I think you could do away with one of them. Paragraph 2 seems close to being a full solution to me. Again, I would point out that $(x_1,y_1) \in f^{-1}(V)$ and $(x_2,y_2) \in f^{-1}(W)$.

Comment: @MikeF Yes, is  a matter of notation. I'll edit it anyway.